# Replacing elements of one list with another list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `J1,J2` containing lists. I want to replace and insert elements of `J2` into `J1`. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

J1=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]

J2=[[1,4]]
for i in range(0,len(J2)):
    J=[J2[i][j] for j in J1]
    print(J)
```

The error is

```
in <listcomp>
    J=[J2[i][j] for j in J1]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

The expected output is

```
[[1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
```

Comment: The `j` is not a number here. It is a list from `J1`.

Comment: "I want to replace and add elements of J2 into J1" - exactly what *process* do you want this to follow? What should happen, for example, if there is more than one list in either of the lists of lists? What do you mean exactly by "add"? Are you talking about *inserting* elements into the lists, or about *summing* some elements together, or just what?

Comment: I want to insert elements. For the time being, I just want to consider one list of list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by the fact that, in your code, `j` is an element of `J1`, more specifically, the first time, `j = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]`. This is indeed a list, and not an integer or a slice, as requested by `J2[i][j]`.

This should work, in your case where J2 is shorter than J1:

```py
J1=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]

J2=[[1,4]]
for i in range(0,len(J2[0])):
    J1[0][i] += J2[0][j]

print(J1)
```

For a more general approach:

```py
J1 = [[1, 4]]
J2 = [[0, 0, 0, 9]]

index = 0
J = [[]]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while index < len(J1[0]) and index < len(J2[0]):
        J[0].append(J1[0][index] + J2[0][index])
        index += 1
        if index == len(J1[0]):
            J[0].extend(J2[0][index:])
        elif index == len(J2[0]):
            J[0].extend(J1[0][index:])

    print(J)
```

Comment: Note that `J` is not defined.

Comment: Good call, I misstyped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unpack each element instead of calling the list element from the index, you can use `zip_longest` from `itertools`. The function `zip_longest` will zip to the longest list, and fill in null values for the shorter list once the last element has been unpacked. The `zip` function from python standard library stops at the shortest length list.

Also, we can implement recursion, so that it can handle any dimension of lists.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

J1=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
J2=[[1,4]]

def replace_list(J1,J2):
    j = []
    for j1,j2 in zip_longest(J1, J2, fillvalue=[]):
        if not isinstance(j1,int) and not isinstance(j2,int): # When J2 and J1 are a inner list
            j.append(replace_list(j1,j2))
        elif not j2: # When J2 is shorter than J1 
            j.append(j1)
        else:
            j.append(j2)
    return j

J = replace_list(J1,J2)
print(J) # [[1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]

# This can handle uneven lists in multiple dimensions as well.
J1=[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    ]
J2=[
    [1,4],
    [9, 8, 7, 6],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    ]
    
J = replace_list(J1,J2)
print(J) # [[1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0], [9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```